# Angular EventEmitter parent This equals with the EventEmitter

Tags: angular, eventemitter, angular-dynamic-components

My problem is when going back to the parent element after EventEmitter trigger my "this" is the EventEmitter itself at the parent, hence I cannot access any methods/variables which are part of the parent. Am I doing something wrong, or it this how it should work?

Maybe the issue comes from the dynamic component? Not sure as I think this is my only different compared to other example where this. seems to be working.

My child component:

```
@Input() item: someItem;
@Output() newItemEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

createElement()
  {
    this.newItemEvent.emit(this.item);
  }
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form">
    <mat-form-field class="form__input">
      <input matInput placeholder="Name"  name="name" type="name"  [(ngModel)]="item.name">
    </mat-form-field>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" (click)="createElement()">Create</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Parent:

```
  //create the structure element
  create (element)
  {
    //do something
    this.myMethod(element); 
   }
```

HTML

```
<ndc-dynamic 
  [ndcDynamicInputs]="{item: selectedElement}" 
  [ndcDynamicComponent]="selectedElement.component" 
  [ndcDynamicOutputs]="{newItemEvent: create}">
</ndc-dynamic>
```

This is my error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.myMethod is not a function
  at Object.create [as newItemEvent] .....
```

Well this is the event emitter so yeah there is no method "myMethod".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a method of the component class as an argument to `ndcDynamicOutputs`.

```
[ndcDynamicOutputs]="{newItemEvent: create}"
```

Inside the `create` method, you access `this`.

```
create() {
  this.myMethod()
}
```

The thing is, when you pass the method as an argument, it doesn't have the `this` context from the class anymore. `this` is going to have another value. So you have two options here:

The first one is to attach `this` using the `bind` function.

```js
getCreateMethod() {
  return this.create.bind(this);
}
```

```html
[ndcDynamicOutputs]="{newItemEvent: getCreateMethod() }">
```

Another option would be to refactor your create method so it doesn't access `this`, but maybe this isn't feasible.

Comment: Thank you Allan, works as a charm, good to know tricks like this!